# User defined function sql, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'return'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-functions

I'm trying to write a function that takes an input of a date, and calculates the difference between current day and the inputed date, then returns it as an integer of days. (So if I input yesterday 2015-5-8 it returns 1). So far I'm getting this error and can't really figure out what's wrong. Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE FUNCTION DnevnaRazlika
(@OdKdaj nvarchar(15))
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN 
declare @return INT
select @return = DATEDIFF(day,@OdKdaj, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))
end
return @return 
end
```

Edit: Using Microsoft SQL management studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too much `end`s. try below code

```
CREATE FUNCTION DnevnaRazlika ( @OdKdaj NVARCHAR(15) )
RETURNS INT
AS 
    BEGIN 
        DECLARE @return INT
        SELECT  @return = DATEDIFF(day, @OdKdaj, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
        RETURN @return 
    END
```

Comment: This answer was helpful because it told me that the issue truly was syntax (Although mine for a different reason.). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

problem here is you are having end two time

```
CREATE FUNCTION DnevnaRazlika
(@OdKdaj nvarchar(15))
RETURNS INT 
AS
BEGIN 
declare @return INT
select @return = DATEDIFF(day,@OdKdaj, CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))
--end remove this end than it will work 
return @return 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create Function a123(@a Int,@b Int) returns Int as 
begin 
    return (@a + @b)
end

select dbo.a123(30,20)
```

Comment: Answers should also include a small explanation, even in the case of very simple ones.